# EventCallback vs Action not working in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

I'm trying to build a Proof of Concept with nested components.

I have a main-component which is declared the following

```
public abstract class VoidHtmlComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> OnClick { get; set; }
}
```

and I pass an instance of e.g a `TableHead` to my `Table` component

```
<Shared.RazorComponents.Table TableHead="@(new TableHead{ OnClick = HandleTableHeadClick})" >
</Shared.RazorComponents.Table>

@code{
    private void HandleTableHeadClick(MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"TableHead has been clicked ...");
    }
}
```

This will not build stating

> Client\Pages\Table.razor(6,213): Error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'HandleTableHeadClick' to non-delegate type 'EventCallback'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

I guess blazor is doing some magic here to convert the `Action<MouseEventArgs>` to an `EventCallback<MouseEventArgs>` but I am stuck at this point. I also changed the parameter to `Action<MouseEventArgs>` which throws an error on runtime saying the cast is invalid.

Already tried using EventCallbackFactory but got stuck there as well.

Using `OnClick = new EventCallbackFactory().Create(this, HandleTableHeadClick)` throws

> Function statements require a function name

at runtime.

Comment: if you change `OnClick = HandleTableHeadClick` to `OnClick = e => HandleTableHeadClick(e)` does it work?

Comment: @Ben throws `Client\Pages\Table.razor(6,213): Error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'EventCallback<MouseEventArgs>' because it is not a delegate type` during build

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you create an instance of the `TableHead` just like a property.
Since we don't know anything about the `Table` component it self I just assume that the issue is is around there.

The markup for using `Renderfragments` for this case would like like something like this:

```
<Shared.RazorComponents.Table>
    <TableHead Context="context">
         <p>put what ever you want to render here. Like the nested component with event handler</p>
    </TableHead>
</Shared.RazorComponents.Table>
```

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0) as a reference.

Comment: I am aware of the `RenderFragment` to be used. And yes. `TableHead` is a property of the `Table`-component. I won't use `RenderFragment` as the head's content is generated dynamically inside the `Table` from a given list of `Column`-items